# Android parse.com I can't get second user from data base

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have two tables in data base. One is user ad the second is transaction that have pointer to the first user, pointer to the second user and int. When I try make and display list I have error. I want to display all rows that CurrentUser is in first column:

```
ParseUser cu = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
query.whereEqualTo("first", cu);
```

and list it with firstUser, secondUser and int:

from Adapter:

```
ParseObject taskObject = mTask.get(position);


    ParseUser first = taskObject.getParseUser("first");
    holder.firsthp.setText(first.getUsername());


    ParseUser second = taskObject.getParseUser("second");
    holder.secondhp.setText(second.getUsername()); //this line make error

    int ile = taskObject.getInt("ile");
    holder.taskhp.setText(Integer.toString(ile));

    return convertView;
```

This is how transakcja table looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh83p.png

When I saving transaction (when transaction table is clear, don't have any records) and immediately read it works but when I logout and login it crashes.
And here is entire code for toDoActivity Task Adapter and hplayout:

I had problems with pasting code here so I pasted it on pastebin
        http://pastebin.com/2wtQLJXE

Comment: put my answer below, let me know if it fixes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know the problem. When you are calling your query on the transaction table, the two User's are Pointers to ParseObjects, or ParseUsers in this case. You need to ensure that these objects are FETCHED as well by the ParseQuery in order to properly access their data. They are ParseObjects with data from another table, Parse does not automatically retrieve them so you must tell Parse to do so when you need that data.

Looking at ParseQuery documentation for Android we find the [include](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#include(java.lang.String)) method.

> public ParseQuery include(String key)
>
> Include nested ParseObjects for the provided key.
> You can use dot notation to specify which fields in the included object that are also fetched.

You want to use this to include columns names to Pointers of ParseObjects so the query fetches them at the same time as fetching the rest of the data from the table, in this case your transaction table.

Add this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("transakcja");
query.whereEqualTo("first", cu);
query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
query.include("first");
query.include("second");
```

The reason first is having no null issues, is it is the Pointer to the current ParseUser logged in, which doesn't need to be fetched as it's data is accessible. The second one is **not fetched**, therefore adding the include to the query SHOULD fix this :). Make sure to also include the column "first" because I'm sure your future ParseQuery's will not always be between the current user and non-current second user

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to fix it for few hours. I can't give up vote to your answer because I have to low reputation but when I get more pionts I will do it :D